# android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I add a `ListView` on runtime like this:

```
     MainMenue =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Unit);
    // remove all controls 
    LinearLayout formLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.submenue);
    formLayout.removeAllViews();
    menueview = new ListView(getApplicationContext());               
    menueview.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    menueview.setLayoutParams(params);
    menueview.setAdapter(new submenueadapter(menueview.getContext(), MainMenue));
    // Set the on Item 
    SetMenueOnClick() ;
    formLayout.addView(menueview);
```

and then I add a item click listener like this:

```
 public void SetMenueOnClick() {
     menueview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
              final String text = (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
          }
     });
 }
```

But then I have an error:

```
06-03 10:59:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(14732):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2109)
android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

at this line:

```
final String text = (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
```

Any idea how to get the text in this issue? the adapter looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shortmenue, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contents);

    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);

    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alternate_list_color);
    return rowView;
}
```

and `R.layout.shortmenue` is simple, only a `TextView` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/contents"
                android:textSize="34dp" 

                />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your row is a `TextView` wrapped by a `LinearLayout` so you might want to do this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view; // get the parent layout view
TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.contents); // get the child text view
final String text = tv.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are running on a similar problem but you sure you have targeted a linearLayout:

**Delete** the file **gen/your.app.package/R.java.**

This happens because of a xml bug, when you delete R.java it will be recreated on the next build/run.

Comment: Worked! Stupid enough :p

Comment: Or just try to hit the REBUILD button

Answer (score 1):

I just added android:id="@+id/my_layout" to LinearLayout that wrapped TextView and that solved similar problem.

Comment: Strangely enough this solved my list_item.xml problem too, where I had multiple items in it but no id set for the LinearLayout containing them. Somehow android can't distinguish it from a normal View, probably because it doesn't have the R.layout type without the id, so it tries to cast it and fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just renamed inserted view object.

Like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/newTextViewName"
    android:textSize="34dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case an XML contained a TextView, but I made a mistake writing

```
final TextView text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_text, layout);
```

instead of

```
final TextView text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_text, layout, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by replacing

```
final String text = (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
```

with

```
TextView temp= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

This works for me.